# How to change the images in asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, background

I downloaded a project from here https://sites.google.com/site/freeprojectseminar/asp-net-projects/gym-management-system-in-asp-net

Its working fine, but I want to change the background images that come after program start.
I tried to edit some pictures in paint from images and resources folder and saved it successfully, but there is no change coming when I start the program. 
Please tell me how to change these background images.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: That is not asp.net it is winforms!

Comment: @Zaki, can you please explain? It looks like ASP.NET to me.

Comment: asp.net is when the application runs in browser, winform application runs on desktop

Comment: So how do I change the images?
Can anybody answer, please.